# SQL Server 2008 : update the table with primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I modified the table from the development database and want to update the same table on production database with new data from the development server. Please let me explain this...

For example,

Development Table:

TableName: `ParentTable` (`ParentID` is auto increment# and primary key)

```
ParentID        Name    Value
------------------------------
1               Z       A-1    (change value to Z)
2               B       B-1    (will delete the record completely)
3               C       C-1
4               D       D-1
5               E       E-1
6               F       F-1
7               G       G-1
8               H       H-1
9               I       I-1
```

Production table:

TableName: `ParentTable` (`ParentID` is auto increment# and primary key)

```
ParentID        Name    Value
-----------------------------
1               A       A-1 
2               B       B-1  
3               C       C-1
4               D       D-1
5               E       E-1
6               F       F-1
7               G       G-1
8               H       H-1
9               I       I-1
```

First, note that `ParentID` is auto increment# and also a primary key. There are also relationship between the `ParentTable` with others.

On the DEV server, I changed name from "A" to "Z" with `parentID# 1`, and I also deleted the record for `parentID# 2`.

Since `parentID# 2` record has been deleted on the DEV server, assume that I will delete any records from other tables that associated `ParentID# 2` on production server.

What is a good way to update the `ParentTable` on production that looks exactly same as the `ParentTable` on the DEV server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a one time update or is this an ongoing/instantaneous need?

Comment: Only one time update.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two databases are on the same server (or linked server). You could do an [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) query. If not you could update the values with an [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) query.

```
MERGE INTO ProductionDB.Schema.ParentTable A
USING DevelopmentDB.Schema.ParentTable B
ON A.ParentID = B.ParentID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET A.Name = B.Name, A.Value = B.Value;
```

Of course replace your server/database names. But this an rough example of what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, the databases are on the different servers, but I already have the LinkedServer created.  Can I still use MERGE?

Comment: Yes. This should work over a linked server as well. As long as you can reference both tables.

Comment: Is it possible that you can provide me the example based on those two tables I posted?  I am afraid that I will not be able to figure that out on the night of maintenance.  Thanks.

Comment: For the MERGE, I don't need to do this first "set identity_insert Prod.dbo.ParentTable on" correct.  It will take care of the primary key right?

Comment: That is correct. The merge query simply updates the data using data from another table.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try something like:

```
declare @parentOffset int
begin transaction

select @parentOffset = max(ParentID) from Prod.dbo.ParentTable (holdlock)

set identity_insert Prod.dbo.ParentTable on

insert into Prod.dbo.ParentTable ( ParentID , Name , Value )
select Dev.dbo.ParentTable.ParentID + @parentOffset , Dev.dbo.ParentTable.Name , Dev.dbo.ParentTable.Value
from Dev.dbo.ParentTable.ParentTable

set identity_insert Prod.dbo.ParentTable off

insert into Prod.dbo.ChildTable ( ParentID , SomeOtherField )
select Dev.dbo.ChildTable.ParentID + @parentOffset , Dev.dbo.ChildTable.SomeOtherField

commit transaction
```

Obviously, test it out against an offline copy of things before you pull the trigger in production, and would put in some error handling, but this should get the job done.  It *won't* test to see if there are already existing values in the table, but you could handle that with a slight modification & going through a temp table.  It's unclear if that's your situation, or whether you just want to add.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the example. That works for me.  I will create another table and test it offline first.