# C#-Replacing Sharepoint list data nightly

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list on a site that I want to update nightly from a SQL server DB, preferably using C#.  Here is the catch, I do not know if any records were removed, added, or if any field in any record has been updated.  I would believe then the simplest thing to do is remove the data from the list and then replace it with the new list data.  But is there any simple way to do this?  I would hate to remove 3000+ items line by line from the list and then add the 3000+ records one at a time.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:  Merging data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638619/sql-server-2008-update-the-table-with-primary-key?noredirect=1#comment58959010_35638619

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately I am not updating two database tables rather I am updating a Sharepoint list from a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its up to your environment. If you not that much load on the systems in the night, i would prefer one of the following ways:

1) Build a timerjob, delete the list (not the items one by one, cause this is slow), recreate the list and import the items from the db. When we are talking about 3.000 - 5.000 Elements, this is not that much and i think done under 10 Minutes.

2) Loop through the sharepoint list with the items and check field by field if it was updated within the db and if yes, update it.

I would preferr to delete the list and import the complete table, cause we are talking about not that much data.

Another way, which is a good idea, is to use BCS or BDC. Then you would have the data always in place and synched with the db. Look at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163782.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee231515(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I had a feeling it wasn't going to be that simple.  I will look at the BCS/BDC option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no "easy" and/or elegant way to delete all the items in a list, like the delete statement in SQL. You can either delete the entire list and recreate it if the list can be easily created from a list definition or, if your concern is performance, since SP 2007 the SPWeb Class has a method called ProcessBatchData. You can use it to batch process commands to avoid the performance penalty of issuing 6000 separate commands to the server. However, it still requires you to pass an ugly XML that contains a list of all the items to be deleted or added.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look up the ProcessBatchData statement,  it wasn't exactly as I hoped but at least I can increase performance a little from thousands of separate commands.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way is to enumerate all the rows from the database and see if each row already exists in the SharePoint list using a primary field value. If it already exists, simply update them[1]. Otherwise you can add a new item.

[1] - Optionally, while updating them we can compare the list item field values with database column values. Only if there is a change in any of the field, update it. Otherwise skip it.